# My query giving different result in my ORG and Community

Tags: soql, developer-console

I am using same VF page and apex class for this query and given access for community user. Please help me . Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Id, Title, (SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLinks) 
  FROM ContentDocument
```

Comment: This can be a permission issue.

Comment: which type of permission can you please elaborate. I have given access of VF page and Apex class to community user profile.

Comment: Record level permissions and field level for community profile and internal user profile.

Comment: i have given but still i am not getting list of files in my VF page

Comment: If you run the the same query from the developer console you do get results? How is your sharing model configured? There is a difference between internal and external access.